# AppEngine Get HOST of incoming request

Tags: google-app-engine, host

I have an API and would like to check that I only process requests from certain hosts, using self.request.host always brings back the current API host, not the requesting URL's host...any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do You mean `self.request.remote_addr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Request` object has a property called `remote_addr` that should give you IP address of the origin of the request. See [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_remote_addr).

Comment: ...and once you have the IP address, you can use `socket.gethostbyaddr()` to get the domain name of the host.

Comment: @bgporter: have actually done that with AppEngine? I thought that socket support was disabled.

Comment: Oooh, no. Forgot that not all modules are available on AppEngine. I should take today off -- that's my second "never mind" here today...

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean referer?

```
self.request.headers.get("Referer")
```

Comment: I don't think that is what @Chris is looking for. The definition of the Referer header is "This is the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed."